# Sliding new image in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition

**SWIFTUI - ANIMATED TRANSITIONS**

I want to slide a new image from right to left when I click the next button and from left to right when I click the previous button. The sliding should be animated. Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var index: Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            image?
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .transition(.slide)
                .animation(.default)
        }
        .onAppear(perform:loadImage)
        
        Button("Next", action: {
            index += 1
            loadImage()
        })
        
        Button("Previous", action: {
            index -= 1
            loadImage()
        })
    }
    
    
    func loadImage() {
        let strname = String(format: "image%02d", index)
        image = Image (strname)
    }
    
    struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            DetailView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can attach an `id` to the `image` so that whenever you update the image, SwiftUI sees 2 different views — making it animate the transition.

**Edit:** use the `move` transition to control direction.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var index: Int = 1
    @State private var forwards = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            image?
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .transition(
                    .asymmetric(
                        insertion: .move(edge: forwards ? .trailing : .leading),
                        removal: .move(edge: forwards ? .leading : .trailing)
                    )
                )
                .id(UUID())

            Button("Next") {
                index += 1
                forwards = true
                withAnimation {
                    loadImage()
                }
            }

            Button("Previous") {
                index -= 1
                forwards = false
                withAnimation {
                    loadImage()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadImage)
    }

    func loadImage() {
        let name = String(format: "image%02d", index)
        image = Image(name)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Image slides in whenever it changes. If Next pressed, image slides in from right, otherwise, left.]

Comment: Thanks, this worked beautifully. How do I set the slide direction? For next click, the image should slide from right to left and for previous it should be from left to right.

Comment: Fantastic, works perfectly. Thank you so much for your quick help! I had spent almost a week trying to achieve this.

Comment: @abcom no problem, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry, did it now.