# Incorrect removal edge when switching direction in a SwiftUI asymmetric transition animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I am trying to animate a 'slide-show' like effect of a series of images in SwiftUI.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318659/sliding-new-image-in-swiftui) answer on Stack Overflow, and attempted to implement it. At first, it seemed to work. But, when you switch direction, the image that needs to be removed is removed from the wrong direction.  It seems the removal edge just isn't recognising the initial change in direction.

Here's an example video: https://streamable.com/fmbcij

```
import SwiftUI

struct Slideshow: View {
    
    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var index: Int = 1
    @State private var forwards = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            image?
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .transition(
                    .asymmetric(
                        insertion: .move(edge: forwards ? .trailing : .leading),
                        removal: .move(edge: forwards ? .leading : .trailing)
                    )
                )
                .animation(.default)
                .id(UUID())

            Text(index.formatted())
            Text(String(forwards)).padding(.bottom)

            Button("Next", action: {
                index += 1
                forwards = true
                loadImage()
            })

            Button("Previous", action: {
                index -= 1
                forwards = false
                loadImage()
            })
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadImage)
    }

    func loadImage() {
        let strname = String("Test\(index)")
        image = Image(strname)
    }
}

struct Slideshow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Slideshow()
    }
}
```

I have tried editing this code to keep track of any direction switches, and make sure the insertion/removal fields are correct. I have also tried delaying the animation, to make sure the removal edge was correct. I also tried a using a conditional if extension, see code below. Neither of these were successful.

```
.if(forwards) {
    $0.transition(
        .asymmetric(
            insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
            removal: .move(edge: .leading)
        )
    )
}
.if(!forwards) {
    $0.transition(
        .asymmetric(
            insertion: .move(edge: .leading),
            removal: .move(edge: .trailing)
        )
    )
}
```

Is this a SwiftUI bug, or is there something that can be done to resolve this?

Comment: I've run into the same problem. It seems that a view uses the removal transition specified when the view was inserted. Changing it post insertion doesn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you cannot modify the transition after a view has been inserted.

The only solution I've found is to change transition, then change the ID of the view. However, this will trigger a view insertion, which will trigger the currently defined insertion transition. As such, you'll need to use an insertion transition of .identity to prevent an animation when you change the ID and a new view is inserted.

IOW, you would need three transitions: one that has the insertion transition you want, with a removal that is .identity, a second, with an insertion of .identity and .move(edge: .leading) and third with .move(edge: .trailing).